# Fleck2 websocket message > 65535 bytes

Tags: c#, websocket

I am using Fleck2 library, .net 2.0 build from "flex2-master" source.
Application is C# on .net 3.5.

All my HTML5 clients face errors/connection loss when sending message > 65535 bytes length.

With messages shorter - everything works fine.

I got the impression that package length calculation on Flex2 may be incorrect - but I am really the one who faces this problem? Maybe there are other places where I should look at?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug remaining on Fleck2 (that's fixed in latest Fleck) - file Hybi13Handler.cs, function public static byte[] FrameData(byte[] payload, FrameType frameType), line:

```
var lengthBytes = payload.Length.ToBigEndianBytes<ushort>();
```

should be replaced to:

```
var lengthBytes = payload.Length.ToBigEndianBytes<ulong>();
```